# Anyway to connect A/V cables to a laptop?

Tags: ports, pin, av-cable, av-receiver

I want to connect the red, white and yellow A/V cables from an A/V camera receiver to my laptop so that I can cast the video from the camera to my laptop screen. But there are no A/V ports in my laptop to connect the A/V receiver. I tried searching for A/V to usb adaptor but couldn't find any.
Is there anything I can do to connect the A/V receiver to my laptop.

Comment: Will your laptop take a PCMCIA card?

Comment: @spikey_richie yes it will

Answer (score 1):

The device you're looking for is a "[video] capture card". (There are USB 2.0 ones, as well as CardBus/PCMCIA for older laptops.)

Pay attention to what input formats are supported. The yellow video cable is "composite video", which should be supported by nearly all capture devices. (Red and white are analog audio.)

---

If your camera supports FireWire (DV) digital video capture, it would provide better video quality than analog composite video, but unfortunately FireWire adapters can only be connected to PCI directly (including PCIe, CardBus/PCMCIA, ExpressCard), but not via USB. Some older laptops have a "micro" FireWire port built in.